# How to get the client IP address from the request made to webservice

Tags: c#, .net, web-services, file-upload

I have a webservice hosted in my IIS... I need to find out the clientIP address when the client use my service directly

like http://MyIpAddress/MyApplication/MyWebServiceClass.asmx

and is it possible to read file from the client machine? If so how can I do it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/492952/how-to-retrieve-pc-name-of-client-from-c-webservice

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try calling

```
Request.UserHostAddress
```

[HttpRequest.UserHostAddress Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.userhostaddress.aspx)

With regards to accessing a file from the client, this would need be achieved by first uploading the file to the server.

Checkout the following on uploading files to a web service:

[ASMX file upload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4799468/asmx-file-upload)

[Create a simple file transfer Web service with .NET](http://www.zdnetasia.com/create-a-simple-file-transfer-web-service-with-net-39251815.htm)

Answer (score 8):

You should have a plain old HTTP Context at your disposal in ASMX:

```
        HttpContext.Current.Request.UserHostAddress
```

Also re: "Is it possible to read a file from the client machine" - this all depends on your implementation.  If you're making a web service for your intranet and you work in a small(ish) business environment, you probably can given the proper planning w/ your network guy (not advocating this as a good idea, just a possibility).

To further elaborate, if you are in your small office environment and you get a request from 192.168.1.55 and you know that every client machine in your network has a lastLoginData.txt file in the C drive, AND you have the appropriate configurations for UNC access to the client by the machine hosting the service, getting at "\\" + ip + "\c$\lastLoginData.txt" would be possible.  You'd be creating a potentially horrible security issue for yourself, but it'd be possible.

In most normal cicumstances though, no, you will not have access to client disk from the Web Service - some sort of upload will likely have to occur first.

Comment: Is there any way to get read the file on knowing the address?

Comment: Side note: Use IPAddress.Parse to resolve the string into an IPAddress object. Then you can do stuff like. Equals(IPAddress.Loopback) to test if the request is coming from the local machine, etc.

Answer (score 0):

```
        String ip = HttpContext.Current.Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR"];

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(ip))
        {
            ip = HttpContext.Current.Request.ServerVariables["REMOTE_ADDR"];
        }
        else
        {
            ip=ip.Split(',')[0];
        }

        return ip;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
            string hostName = Dns.GetHostName();
            Console.WriteLine(hostName);

            // Get the IP from GetHostByName method of dns class. 
            string IP = Dns.GetHostByName(hostName).AddressList[0].ToString();
```